# Betti numbers of a group times a complex variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, betti-numbers

I am currently studying cohomology groups of complex algebraic varieties, spending a lot of time on computing Betti numbers. I came across several manifolds which have a discrete symmetry group (like e.g.  $\mathbb{Z}_2$). So my question:
For a complex algebraic variety $\mathcal{M}$, is it possible to relate the Betti numbers of
$\mathcal{M}$ to those of $\mathcal{M}\times \mathbb{Z}_n$? I know that in general for product spaces, the Künneth formula can be used to get the Betti-numbers. But is this also true if a finite group is multiplied with a smooth manifold?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: Yes, this should follow immediately from the Kunneth formula. What are the Betti numbers of a finite group ?(hint, it has the discrete topology)

Comment: Hay, thank you for your quick answer. But are you sure this is true? The problem I have here is that if the manifold M is d-dimensional (complex dimension), then M×Zn will also be d-dimensional. The first Betti number of Z_n is 1; Hence the Betti numbers would go up to 2d+1, which does not make sense for a d-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Or is only the zeroth Betti number of a finite group nonzero?

Comment: Yeah only the 0th Betti number is nonzero (corresponding to connected components)